# put a popup when it detects no internet in IONIC

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework

I'm new to IONIC, I'm trying to display a popup when there is no internet service. but I have problems because I need to inject $ ionicPopup, and do not know how.

This is my code:

```
.config(function ($httpProvider,$ionicPopup) {

$httpProvider.interceptors.push(function ($rootScope, $q,$ionicPopup) {
        return {
            request: function (config) {
                config.timeout = 5000;
                return config;
            },
            responseError: function (rejection) {
                switch (rejection.status){
                    case 408 :
                        alert("time out");
                        break;
                    case 0 :
                    $injector.$ionicPopup.alert({
                      title: 'Error!',
                      subTitle: 'not internet'
                     })

                       alert("no internet");
                    break;


                }
                return $q.reject(rejection);
            }
        }
    })
```

and this is the error that I have:

```
 Uncaught Error: [$injector:cdep] Circular dependency found: $http <- $templateRequest <- $compile <- $ionicTemplateLoader <- $ionicPopup <- $http <- $templateFactory <- $view <- $state
```

I'm doing this configuration so that each time it is detected that can not make a request $ http, the popup display

Comment: Well, you are using `$http` that uses `$ionicPopup` who uses `$http` causing a circular reference that makes the injector to fail.

Comment: @LenilsondeCastro then I can do? I do not know much about this.

Comment: It is necessary to make a request $ http or could be a plugin?

Comment: Mr @AdsHan pointed us a good issue. If you need intercept the `$http` requests, this is not possible using `$ionicPopup`. However, if your intention is just keep the user aware of network issues, it can be done another way.

Answer (score 0):

first install this plugin   cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information plugin

use this code

```
module.run(function($rootScope, $cordovaNetwork) {
    // listen for Offline event
    $rootScope.$on('$cordovaNetwork:offline', function(event, networkState, $ionicPopup) {
        $ionicPopup.alert({
            title: 'Error!',
            subTitle: 'not internet'
        })
    })
})
```